# Proving that $H_n(X,A) \cong H_n(X/A, A/A)$... why is this diagram commutative?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Consider the following proposition from Hatcher's Algebraic Topology:

[image]

I read the proof and the only thing I'm having trouble to understand is the final part where the author says "From the commutativity of the diagram..." I just don't get why this diagram is commutative. Could someone please explain it to me? Thanks.

Comment: excision is part of it...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Hi, now you know why I was asking the last question xD...

Comment: I thought excision was used only to prove that the other two horizontal maps are isomorphisms. Could we get an isomorphism from $H_n(X,A)$ to $H_n(X/A,A/A)$ just by taking the composition of all the isomorphisms and forget about commutativity of the diagram?

Comment: @Twink Commutativity is needed to ensure that the composition of the isomorphisms is the desired $q_*:H_n(X,A) \to H_n(X/A,A/A)$. Can you tell explicitly where you got stuck?

Answer (score 2):

The diagram of homology groups commutes because the diagram at the level of spaces commutes and homology is a functor.